# Windows service and kernel driver relationship

Tags: c, windows, winapi

After lurking around S.O. for a long time, it's time to join this awesome community of developers and hopefully get some answers to my questions. My first post so please be gentle.

I am trying to create a service and a driver "relationship", but I am very confused.

As an example, take the following:

- MyService.exe
- MyDriver.sys

I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/the-complete-service-sample) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-very-small-kmdf--driver) article with small changes. Now my questions are:

- Why do I have to start each of them manually using [StartService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-startservicea)? I thought that there can be a "relationship" between them so I only need to start MyService.exe and MyDriver.sys would also load automatically.
- How can I make them depend on each other? For example, if MyService.exe is stopped, unload MyDriver.sys as well, or the other way around.
- How to "protect" MyService.exe from being exploited? Do I need something like [ObCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-driver-samples/obcallback-callback-registration-driver/) or this does not apply for MyService.exe?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is considered good pratice to only ask one question in a question-post. I may be wrong but it seems to me that the first two questions are closely related (and therefore can be considered as "one question") while the last question is about another topic. Maybe it would make sense to make two independent question-posts?

Comment: Re "*if MyService.exe is stopped, unload MyDriver.sys*", Services receive an event when they are about to be stopped.

Comment: @SupportUkraine Thanks, I edited and removed C++. As for the questions, I'm not sure how to ask in another post because it's just one line. I haven't even gotten past the first question yet to be able to.

Comment: @ikegami Do you mean SvcCtrlHandler (case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP)? Is that the "final" action? because it seems it will be "pending" to stop and I might unload the driver too early.

Comment: You can specify dependencies when creating the service using [`CreateServiceW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-createservicew), or update dependencies on an existing service by calling [`ChangeServiceConfigW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-changeserviceconfigw). I don't know whether driver dependencies get unloaded when a service is stopped.

Comment: @IInspectable Interesting! Do you know of any existing examples? Thank you.

Comment: service dependency only affect start up order. Driver will not unload automatically because of the dependency (since there are possible other drivers/services/apps that may need to access it). So you may write a code in service and driver - service will start driver if not running and subscribe to it. When exiting - service will unsubscribe form driver. In driver - when last subscriber has left - driver may unload automatically

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky I see. I have research if you can unload the driver from within, but could not find such solution. One solution found with ZwUnload but they say it's not safe.

Comment: Depending on what your driver is doing - I personally will just leave it loaded and doing nothing even after service is stopped (till service is restarted and asks driver to do something).
I think you need to unload driver only during upgrade procedure - which can handle proper order of stopping service, then driver, replacing files and starting driver/server back. In all other scenarios - adding dependency will guarantee that driver is started before service.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky Thanks. What about my first question?

Comment: add dependency of Service to the driver as @IInspectable suggested